# Exam class: Need help formatting simple header for math quiz

Tags: header-footer, multicol, enumitem, exam

I'm trying to format the top of the page with a header that looks like this (with perhaps a bit more vertical space between **Name:** and **Period:**)

[image]

But the code is rendering this:
[image]

Clearly `\hrule` and `\rule` are not the proper commands for the creating the line for students to write their name and period.

Also, placing `\\` after "Unit 3 Quiz (Algebra 2) will not force a line break and place "Rational Exponents and Exponential Equations" on the next line.

Thanks very much for taking time to review and respond to this post!

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
%\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Unit 13 Quiz Rational Exponents and Exponential Equations (25 pts.}}
{}
{Name:\hrule[3in]} 
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Unit 13 Quiz}}
{}
{Name:\answerline} 
\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother

%******************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\SolutionSpace}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{5cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}}% solutions are printed
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{0cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
    \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{1}}% solutions are not being printed
%*********************************************
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](4)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{\#1-2 Rewrite using fractional exponents. (1 pt.) \#3-4 Rewrite in radical form. (1 pt.)}}

%%% Prob #1
\task 
$2^4=16$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\log16_{2} =4$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%%
%%%%Prob #2
\task 
$3^3=27$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\log27_{3}=3$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%Prob #3
\task 
$a^2=b$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\log{a}_{b}=2$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%% Prob #4
\task 
$c^r=m$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\log{c}_{m}=r$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%% Prob #5
% to change the number of "columns" you need to stop and restart tasks. Note the use of \lasttask to reset the counter (task).
\end{tasks}\unskip
\edef\lasttask{\arabic{task}}%
\begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](3)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Compute without a calculator.}}%
\setcounter{task}{\lasttask}
%%% Prob #5
\task
$64^{1/3}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$?$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%% Prob #9
\task
$9^{3/2}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$=$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%% Prob #7
\task
$\biggl(\dfrac{8}{27}\biggr)^{-2/3}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
\colorbox{yellow}{$=$}
\end{solutionorbox}

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to define the header of the first page.

```
% *********************************** first page header  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{head}
\lhead[{\parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{\raggedright \bfseries Algebra II: Unit 13 Quiz \\ Rational Exponents and Exponential Equations}}]{}
\rhead[{\parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{Name:\enspace\hrulefill \\[\baselineskip]%
        Period\enspace\makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill}\enspace(25 points)}}]{}
\extraheadheight[0.7cm]{0cm}
% ***********************************
```

Use the optional arguments of `\lhead` and `\rhead`

```
\rhead[<on the first page>]{< on other pages>}
```

The command `\extraheadheight[0.7cm]{0cm}` gives 0.7cm of additional head height on the first page while maintaining the original height on all pages after the first.

[image: a]